# Topology of sets given by semi-continuous functions

Tags: gn.general-topology

$M$ is a compact space. Assume $f$ is upper semi-continuous on $M$, $g$ is lower semi-continuous on $M$, and $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for any $x\in M$.

If $f(x_0) = g(x_0) $ for some point $x_0\in M$,
Then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
What about the topology of the set of the continuous points of both $f$ and $g$?  Or the topology of the set of $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ (open or closed？)

Thank you!

Comment: For the first question, the set of points of continuity of *any* function is $G_\delta$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211511/set-of-points-of-continuity-are-g-delta.

Comment: For the second question, note $\{f=g\}=\cap\{f-g<1/n\}$.

Comment: The Dirichlet function shows that you can't expect more. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html.